# Filter leading zeroes from numbers using only character operations for input and output

Tags: c

Problem:  to eliminate initial zeroes from numbers besides those followed by '.' or alone.  For example if we input `a-000123+bc+0000.0008-0000+0001.07` , we will get `a-123+bc+0.0008-0+1.07)`.

Using putchar and getchar only. No strings and pointers involved. I have working code, but I think it's confusing and overloaded. Can someone suggest how it might be simplified or an easier algorithm?

```
char curr_char = 0, prev_char = 0,flag=0;
while ((curr_char = getchar()) != '&')
{

    if (isdigit(curr_char) && !(isdigit(prev_char))) 
        flag = 1;
    if (flag)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (curr_char=='0'); else break; 
            curr_char = getchar(); 
        }

        if (curr_char == '.')putchar('0'); 

        while (true) 
        {
            if (isdigit(curr_char))putchar(curr_char); else break;
            curr_char = getchar(); 
        }

        if (curr_char == '.') 
        {
            putchar('.'); 
            while (isdigit(curr_char = getchar()))putchar(curr_char);
        }
        flag = 0;
    }
    else putchar(curr_char);
    prev_char = curr_char;
}
```

Comment: You appear to be the same person as [@Winplexy](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/60956/winplexy). We have already merged several of your accounts, and yet you keep creating more new accounts. What is going on?

Answer (score 7):

I see a number of things that could be improved here.

### Include the appropriate headers

The code as posted is just a fragment, but only a few additional lines would make it into a complete program.  It's usually best to provide a complete program for review.  With that said, the missing headers are these:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
```

### Check for `EOF`

The code currently looks for the `&` character, but that's not in the specification.  It would probably make more sense to look for the end of file which is `EOF`.

### Restructure your code

Any time you find yourself writing `while (true)` and then putting a conditional `break` within the loop, this should be a strong indication that something is not quite right. Also, lines like this:

```
if (curr_char=='0'); else break;
```

are really quite awful.  That could easily have been written instead as:

```
if (curr_char != '0')
    break;
```

which makes it much easier to understand.  Even better would have been to write the loop as:

```
while (cur_char != '0') 
    curr_char = getchar();
```

### Eliminate unneeded variables

The code defines `curr_char`, `prev_char` and `flag` but it's possible to rework the algorithm to eliminate at least one of these.  Also, `curr_char` and `prev_char` are good names, but `flag` is not.  It's entirely too generic and doesn't say *what* it's intended to flag.

### Fix your algorithm

If we feed `a03+0.0g` to this code, it should print `a3+0.0g` but what it actually prints is `a30.0` which is clearly not correct.  Part of the problem here is that the implementation of the algorithm is quite convoluted and difficult to follow.  For that reason, I would recommend a different approach.

### Start with a state machine

Starting with a state machine is a very good way to work out what a program should do in advance of writing any code.  Having a design first and **then** writing code is essential to good programming practice.  For example, this state machine can be easily implemented in code.  I used an `enum` to represent the `state` and then a `switch` statement to drive the code.  In it, each transition is labelled as `condition/action`.

[image: zero suppression state machine]

As an example of how to code this, here's the first part of the code including the code for the `nonNum` state:

```
int main() 
{
    enum { nonNum, inInt, inDec, zeroSupp } state = nonNum;
    int ch;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
        switch (state) {
            case nonNum:
                if (ch == '0') {
                    state = zeroSupp;
                } else if (ch > '0' && ch <= '9') {
                    state = inInt;
                    putchar(ch);
                } else {
                    putchar(ch);
                }
                break;
      /* the rest of the state machine goes here */
```

Answer (score 5):

```
char curr_char = 0, prev_char = 0,flag=0;
```

The `getchar` function returns an `int` not a `char`.

```
int curr_char = 0, prev_char = 0;
```

You don't need `flag``.

```
if (isdigit(curr_char) && !(isdigit(prev_char))) 
    flag = 1;
if (flag)
{
```

You can just say

```
if ( isdigit(curr_char) && ! isdigit(prev_char) ) 
{
```

and drop all references to `flag` (including the assignment at the end of the loop).

```
    while (true)
    {
        if (curr_char=='0'); else break; 
        curr_char = getchar(); 
    }
```

This can be more clearly written:

```
    while (true)
    {
        if ( curr_char != '0' ) break; 
        curr_char = getchar(); 
    }
```

The blank then clause was unnecessary.

Even clearer:

```
    while ( '0' == curr_char )
    {
        curr_char = getchar(); 
    }
```

There's no need to loop forever and then break.  Just gate the loop properly.

```
    if (curr_char == '.')putchar('0');
```

There's no need to wait, just output the decimal point as well:

```
    if (curr_char == '.') {
        putchar('0');
        putchar('.');
    }
```

This will save time later.

```
    while (true) 
    {
        if (isdigit(curr_char))putchar(curr_char); else break;
        curr_char = getchar(); 
    }
```

Almost the same except with a statement in the then clause.

```
    while ( isdigit(curr_char) ) 
    {
        putchar(curr_char);
        curr_char = getchar(); 
    }
```

Previously it only ran those two statements if the expression was true, and it still does.

```
    if (curr_char == '.') 
    {
        putchar('.'); 
        while (isdigit(curr_char = getchar()))putchar(curr_char);
    }
    flag = 0;
```

This code is unnecessary.  We already output the decimal point and then any subsequent digits.  Also, we eliminated the `flag` variable.

```
else putchar(curr_char);
```

It's generally easier to follow if either both the `if` and the `else` clauses use `{}` or neither do.  So change this to

```
else
{
    putchar(curr_char);
}
```

It seems like this code has a bug where it doesn't output the first character after a number.  And it may not check for the terminating `'&'` immediately after a number.  I haven't tried to fix this.